# Nested SQL Query Optimization

Tags: postgresql, optimization

is there any better way to write this query to be optimized?

```
SELECT * FROM data d
WHERE d.id IN (SELECT max(d1.id)
               FROM data d1
               WHERE d1.name='A'
                 AND d1.version='2')
```

I am not so good with SQL.

Answer (score 2):

With PostgreSQL v13, you can do it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM data
WHERE name = 'A'
  AND version = '2'
ORDER BY is DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS WITH TIES;
```

That will give you all rows where `id` is the maximum.

If `id` is unique, you can use `FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY` or `LIMIT 1`, which will also work with older PostgreSQL versions.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from other answers that are equally interesting / correct, IN is typically a non-performant keyword. You can remove it by using a slightly different way of writing your own query:

```
SELECT * FROM data d
WHERE d.name = 'A' and d.version = '2' and
d.id = (SELECT max(d1.id) FROM data d1 WHERE d1.name='A' AND d1.version='2')
```